Use Doctrine to pre-load relations with a single JOIN query
I have an entity Author with a relation to Book where an author has many books.
I have many books in my library, and I want to retrieve all of them, along with their author information, in one go using JOIN. It doesn't matter if I retrieve them immediately, I just want to load them in memory.
            $entities = $this->bookRepository
                ->createQueryBuilder('book')
                ->join('book.author', 'a')
                ->getQuery()
                ->setFetchMode(Author::class, 'author', ClassMetadataInfo::FETCH_EAGER)
                ->getResult();

This produces a SELECT query on my books (selecting all Books fields), with a INNER JOIN on the author (selecting no fields). As a result there are many requests to the Author table, as they are not fetched and saved to the unit of work.
What I want to do is diminish the amount of SQL queries and use this JOIN to also load the author in memory and attach it to the unit of work (or cache it).
I find myself quite surprised that there is no easy way to do this. Have I missed something ? Thank you

You can reduce queries by purposefully selecting the entity and joined entity
            $entities = $this->bookRepository
                ->createQueryBuilder('book')
                ->join('book.author', 'a')
                ->select('book', 'a') // addition
                ->getQuery()
                ->setFetchMode(Author::class, 'author', ClassMetadataInfo::FETCH_EAGER)
                ->getResult();

This is related to the "classic N+1 problem". Which you can research more.
